# How to get query rows sorted by number of matched properties?

Tags: mysql, sql, django, django-queryset

I have two models/tables `A` and `Property`. `A` has a many to many relationship to `Property`. A has one field `SomeName` and `Property` also has one field `Value`.

Through my app, I receive a list of `Values`. Now, I want to retrieve the `A` rows who has at least one `Value` from the sent list but I also want to sort those rows according to the number of `Properties` present in the list.

For example, M, N and O are three objects of model A. M has the properties P1, P2, P3, N has the properties P2, P3, P4 and O has the properties P3. I receive a list of values P2, P4. Now, the resultant queryset I want is `<QuerySet [<A: N>, <A: M>]>` if `SomeName` is the string representation of model A.

Django code is preferred but SQL will also suffice.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: @arie haven't been able to solve it. I don't think that deserves a downvote.

Comment: @RahulSarma Hopefully I could be of help. :)

Comment: @RahulSarma - Can you please provide the structure of your table ?

Comment: @RamMehta I have done that above. The `A` table has the column `SomeName` and the Property table has the column `Value`. Of course, for the many to many relationship, there will be an intermediate table, but that's not necessary to mention if you're using django.

Comment: Could you please post the desired result output, this would help in finding an answer.

Comment: @Kevin I did that. Check the second last line. If you want me to expand on that, I guess it would be `<QuerySet [<A: N>, <A: M>]>` if N and M are the string representations of themselves. Does that help?

Answer (score 2):

Feels like you need. Assuming `A` is the model and `Values` is the field in `Properties`.Also `M2MField` is the `Many2Many` field from `A` to `Property`.

```
A.objects.filter(M2MField__Values__in=[list that you have]).annotate(c=Count('M2MField')).order_by('c') #-c for descending order.
```

Comment: Fantastic. That worked. Just maybe edit it to include `from django.db.models import Count`

Comment: Hi, I am making the answer unaccepted again because in your result you are counting the total number of properties object `A` has and sorting the queryset whereas I wanted to sort the queryset according to the number of properties object `A` has which is present in the list submitted by the user. If you can edit your answer, I'll restore the status.